# Suppress "qt5ct: using qt5ct plugin" message

Tags: qt, octave

Every time Octave draws a figure (eg graph), I get the following message:

```
qt5ct: using qt5ct plugin
```

How do I suppress it?

Answer (score 12):

set environment variable `QT_LOGGING_RULES="qt5ct.debug=false"`

Comment: This works and is what comes in their README (despite a typo — there it reads "QT_LOGGIN_RULES[...]").

Comment: False should be the default. This is annoying behavior.

Comment: This can be set in python with: `os.environ["QT_LOGGING_RULES"] = "qt5ct.debug=false"`